# Are negative mass questions on/off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, non-mainstream-physics

I searched for the question about [negative mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Negative+mass) and they aren't closed as off-topic. But recently I posted [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515253/238497) question and somebody voted to close this as off-topic (non-mainstream).

So I want to know what's our policy on questions of negative mass and such.

(Though as for me I would consider this to be on-topic. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) Wikipedia (do see the reference)  article and these [1](https://youtu.be/DW7VBrKmLS8) [2](https://youtu.be/10AP7tio408) videos and there are many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would reconsider your assumption that the question was closed purely because it asked about negative mass. The only way to know for sure is if those who voted to close decide comment on your question (which can no longer happen since you deleted it) or decide to post here. Typically, questions here are not closed purely because of their topic. Conversely, just because other negative mass questions were not closed does not mean that any question you post about negative mass will not be closed. Many other factors are considered.

With that being said, I will say that I was one of the users who voted to close that question. I did not do this because it was about negative mass. I voted to close for multiple reasons.

1. The question was somewhat of a "What if" question. As in "What if negative mass existed, then could we do this thing?"
2. The question was somewhat of a "check my reasoning here". Direct quote: "Now considering the figure I concluded that yes electricity can be generated perpetually. - Is it possible to do so?"
3. The question was also fairly broad. Continuing the previous quote: "If not is there any other method?" This is a very broad question.

So summarizing, you posted a question that was "What if this was real? If it was, is my reasoning correct? If my reasoning is not correct, then how could you do this?" This, to me, is a fairly broad, hypothetical question, and this is why I thought the question should be closed.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped. Also I deleted the question because I don't want to fill the site with misleading question which get negative response by the community.

Comment: @Ramanujan_π I might be wrong on this, but I think it is better to leave a poor question up than to delete it. I think deleting posts is more likely to get you a question ban.

Comment: @Ramanujan_π I would just leave it deleted if you already deleted it. I am sure there are meta posts covering all of that though.

Answer (score 6):

General comments (not addressing OP's [specific question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515253/2451)):

- Questions on [negative effective mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)) are on-topic.
- Questions on particles with [imaginary mass (tachyons)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) and/or [negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) are non-mainstream, and therefore often off-topic.
- Questions on fields with [imaginary mass (tachyonic fields)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_field) are on-topic.

Comment: But what about those question which were previously asked they don't seem to be about effective negative mass? Why aren't they off topic?

Comment: @Ramanujan_π if there are questions about negative mass that are not closed, that does not mean they are on topic; they would still be off topic but they were not closed by those with appropriate powers to do so